# MediaElement working within WPF but not within Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

The code shown below, which plays an audio file, runs fine within my **WPF** application. But when I execute the same code within a **Windows 8.1 app**, I am not getting any exceptions but I am also receiving no sound. Can anyone help?

```
private void myMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myMediaElement.Source =
        new Uri(@"C:\Users\Soph\Music\Addicted.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);
    myMediaElement.Play();
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myMediaElement_MediaOpened(sender,e);
}
```

EDIT:

I have added per the advice the mediaFailed event (followed from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed)

```
    private string GetHresultFromErrorMessage(ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String hr = String.Empty;
        String token = "HRESULT - ";
        const int hrLength = 10;     // eg "0xFFFFFFFF"

        int tokenPos = e.ErrorMessage.IndexOf(token, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (tokenPos != -1)
        {
            hr = e.ErrorMessage.Substring(tokenPos + token.Length, hrLength);
        }

        return hr;
    }

    private void mycontrol_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get HRESULT from event args 
        string hr = GetHresultFromErrorMessage(e);

        // Handle media failed event appropriately 
    }
```

Then i tried to debug this:

Name       Value                                         Type

this      {PracMEWindowsApp.MainPage}                    PracMEWindowsApp.MainPage
e         {Windows.UI.Xaml.ExceptionRoutedEventArgs}     Windows.UI.Xaml.ExceptionRoutedEventArgs
hr        "0x80070003"                                   string
token     "HRESULT - "                                   string
tokenPos   40                                            int
hrLength   10                                            int

What is this hr capturing ? Why is my file not played ?

Comment: `Windows 8.1 App` is not the correct term, you mean Windows Store app, right? Please edit your question, also using the right tag `windows-store-app`

Comment: Did you have try to debug setting `source` and `Play`? It is possible you got Access denied because you have no rights to use files from `C:\`.

Comment: It is good practice to always handle the MediaFailed event

Comment: Yes @kennyzx i did it.. i wanted to inform that it is windows 8.1 app

Comment: Yes i have debug after adding the MediaFailed event @RenDishen

Comment: i added it @user2250152 but i am not able to understand whats it specifying

Answer (score 0):

To access the Music library specify the Music Library capability in app manifest. It is also good practice to always handle the MediaFailed event.

Comment: I have added the MediaFailed event and also edited my question. What is this hr capturing ? Why is my file not played ?

Comment: @SoProgram are you logged as user Soph?

Comment: I dont know why my name got to SoProgram @user2250152

Answer (score 0):

HRESULT 0x80070003 is "Directory Not Found". That would suggest that the media element doesn't like something about the file path. If you get HRESULT 0x80070005 (Access Denied), then it's probably a permissions-related thing.

Comment: Yes i got it. But what i do not get is that i have corrected the path and i am having no exceptions or failedevent, still i cant hear any sound playing. But it worked fine using WPF

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store app does not have access to files in local file system, it runs in a **sandboxed environment** and only has access to its own data folder, a path like `C:\Users\Soph\Music\Addicted.mp3` is unrecognizable.

There are several ways in which you can play the media file.

a.Specify the Music Library capability in `Package.appxmanifest` (this is required), and then

```
private async void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("Addicted.mp3");
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    myMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
}
```

or

b. use `FileOpenPicker`, choose the song manually, you can access any .mp3 file in the file system.

```
private async void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
    var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    myMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
}
```

or

c. Add Addicted.mp3 to your project, and then

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Addicted.mp3");
myMediaElement.Source = uri;
```

you can also set it in XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" Source="Addicted.mp3" />
```

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed explanation. I understood and now gave the right path as mentioned by you. Now its not failing. But also its not giving me any sound. Although i can hear it quite well using WPF. Why not using WindowsAPP ??

Comment: The app has to run as foreground to play the sound, if you switch to other application the sound stops playing. And Which way-a,b,c-are you using?

Comment: The sound is not coming at all. Though it goes through the .Play().. Its the only page right now.. Thats why i m stuck.. ?? @kennyzx

Comment: It should work if you use the 2nd approach, you can use `FileOpenPicker` to choose the mp3, which guarantees the file path is correct.

Comment: I tried the 2nd approach and windows 8.1 app doesnot allow PickSingleFileAsync() rather it allows PickSingleFileAndContinue(), in which i am having trouble in writing the AndContinue() method (Having problem in describing what to give in the arguments of my  myMediaElement.SetSource(); ) @kennyzx

Comment: [PickSingleFileAndContinue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.picksinglefileandcontinue.aspx) is for Windows Phone 8.1. Are you sure your project type is Windows 8.1 not Windows Phone 8.1?